# Is it Possible to achieve Guaranteed Transactional behaviour with Concurrent JmsListeners in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, listener, ibm-mq, spring-transactions, spring-jms

I am using a Spring boot JmsListener to dequeue messages from IBM MQ in a transacted session.

Issue arise when its throughput got restricted around 50 Transactions per second(Dequeue from MQ ,process and save to Database).

TO improve throughput we increased its concurrency and it really helped. But now we can see that at time of app restart, Same message is consumed by multiple concurrent listeners.(This I have concluded by logging thread names).

This does not happen at heavy loads, but at the time of application restart with messages pending to be dequeued.

Is there any other way of achieving high throughput while maintaining atmost one complete consumption with transactional JsmListener?

```
    @Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JmsTransactionManager transactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory());
    return transactionManager;
}
    @Bean
public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory(){
    MQConnectionFactory cf = new MQConnectionFactory();
    try {
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, host);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, Integer.parseInt(port));
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channel);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManager);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "JmsGet (JMS)");
        cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, user);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, password);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SUITE, null);
    } catch (JMSException jmsException) {
        log.error(jmsException.toString());
    }
    return cf;
}
    @Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> listenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConcurrency("2");//Added to increase throughput
    factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager());
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    return factory;
}
@JmsListener(containerFactory = "listenerContainerFactory", destination = "${input_qname}")
public void onMessage(String message) throws Exception{
//if exception -> throw e; 
}
```

Comment: Your logging that has concluded this, can you show us some examples? If you are using transactions it is impossible to have two consumers getting the same message. If this is truly what you are seeing it would be a defect. In answer to your main question though, parallelism is exactly the right thing to be doing to increase processing throughput.

Comment: @MoragHughson thanks for the reply, issue is not easily simulated hence no logs now. But if the listener is consuming msgs from a queue (IBM MQ in this case), How exactly  is the concurrent listening possible? Shouldn't it be like this:
1: MQ share a message to listener but does not DQ this
2: Only one of below at listener:
2a: Success process and save message and give some ack.
2b: Throws exception
3 : Based on above, MQ will either DQ message or detect a rollback and share same msg again due to transaction behaviour.

How is above process possible with Concurrent consumers ?

Comment: Concurrent getting (not browsing) from a queue is possible because the queue manager only gives an individual message to one getter. The application (the listener as you call it) won't be given a message that has been given to someone else, it will given the next one.  If a message is given to an application which then later has an exception, then that transaction will be rolled back, and only then can the same message be given to another application. The queue manager manages the transactions to ensure integrity.